# Can we begin a sentence with 'referring to the Email below'

Tags: grammaticality

Can we begin a sentence with 'referring to the Email below'?

E.g.: Referring to the Email below, I have sent all the required data to you.

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question seems like a request for proof-reading. Please include your research/reference. Visiting [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) would help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it (i.e. it's grammatical), but it probably doesn't have the meaning you want. You are probably trying to say:

> *Regarding* the email below, I have sent all the required data to you.

This means that the required data is referenced in the email and you are responding to it by sending that data.

By contrast, when you say:

> *Referring to* the email below, I have sent all the required data to you.

...you are saying that you (the author) have sent the data, and the fact that you have sent the data is addressed in the email below, and you know this because you have referred to the email.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is grammatical, but I'd rather go with something along the lines of,

> *As indicated/mentioned* in the email below, I have sent all of the required data to you.
>
> *[As] per/In accordance with* the email below, I have sent all of the required data to you.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather say " Ref. The e mail below " , I have sent all the required data to you.

Comment: Why would you rather say that?

Comment: I would use "Pursuant to your email" or "Following up on your email" to indicate that the original email created a task, which you have completed.

Comment: I noticed that it is very  common in business writing , so I am looking at this as a writing issue not as a point of grammar